# Python dataframes how to get the lines that have duplicate count > 1

Tags: python

I have a dataset in which i need to find out the list of lines that are duplicates.
I have user pandas and was able to get the count of the columns by grouping them . However I am not able to figure out the method to print out only the lines that have the value of the count > 1.

Below is my code:

```
def check_for_duplicates_in_batch():
    file_delimiter = "|"
    temp_files_location = input("Location of the temp files:")
    logger.info("File location provided is: {0}".format(temp_files_location))

    # Verify if the folder exists and is valid:
    try:
        # chunk_list = []
        os.chdir(temp_files_location)
        temp_files_name = temp_files_location + "\\finalTempmerged.csv"
        df_chunk = pd.read_csv(temp_files_name, sep=file_delimiter, header='infer', chunksize=100000)
        # print(type(df_chunk))
        for chunk in df_chunk:
            df = chunk_preprocessing(chunk)
            # print(type(df))
        pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None

        df_new = df.groupby(['Id', 'BDate', 'BTimestamp', 'BSequenceNumber', 'BLineNumber']).agg('count')
        logger.info(df_new)  # This prints the grouping with the count> How can I get the rows that have count > 1 

        df['is_duplicated'] = df.duplicated(['Id', 'BDate', 'BTimestamp', 'BSequenceNumber', 'BLineNumber'])
        logger.info("Total duplicated fuel transactions: {0}".format(df['is_duplicated'].sum()))
    except FileNotFoundError:
        logger.error("File location {0} is invalid".format(temp_files_location))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can track duplicates with something like this:

```
df1=pd.read_csv('newdate.csv')

df1

#In [415]: df1                                                                                                                                                                                               
#Out[415]: 
#    Name       Date
#0   Will   9/5/2019
#1   Bill  11/5/2019
#2   Bill  11/5/2019
#3   Bill  11/5/2019
#4   Will   9/5/2019
#5  Lance  11/5/2019
#6   Mark  11/5/2019
#7   Jeff  11/2/2019

df1 = df.sort_values('Name')

bool_series = df1["Name"].duplicated(keep=False) 
#In [413]: bool_series                                                                                                                                                                                       
#Out[413]: 
#1     True
#2     True
#3     True
#7    False
#5    False
#6    False
#0     True
#4     True
#Name: Name, dtype: bool

df1[bool_series]
#   Name       Date
#1  Bill  11/5/2019
#2  Bill  11/5/2019
#3  Bill  11/5/2019
#0  Will   9/5/2019
#4  Will   9/5/2019

df1[~bool_series]
#Out[412]: 
#    Name       Date
#7   Jeff  11/2/2019
#5  Lance  11/5/2019
#6   Mark  11/5/2019
```

Comment: No need to sort the values before finding the duplicates (he may wants the values in the order they were before).

Comment: sorting wont make a difference here.  also the file I am dealing with has 840000 rows of data. my current script outputs the values by grouping the specified columns and the count . What i need in my output is only the rows that have the count value > 1